# Audio has a crackly echo in certain apps? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

Sometimes when I play video in Firefox or start up a game I'll get this horrible crackly echo for all the sounds, when it happens in a game or in Firefox I just restart pulse audio and everything is fine but in Discord no matter what I do I still get the echo. I managed to stop it by ending pulse audio via htop once but it never worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered this by accident myself a couple days ago, in my case if I just let the audio play for about 10-30 seconds it eventually returns to normal.